# C++ - Determine if an angle is between 0 and PI, or PI and 2 PI

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

I have a float value, that represents an angle. I need the quickest way to determine if the angle is between 0 and PI, or PI and 2 PI. If the float value is outside of the range 0 to 2 PI, it should still work.
I have the following, but I fear it is slow compared to other solutions:

```
// float fltValue;
// bool blnResult;
while (fltValue < 0)
{ fltValue += 2 * PI; }
while (fltValue >= 2 * PI)
{ fltValue -= 2 * PI; }
if (fltValue < PI)
{ blnResult = true; }
else
{ blnResult = false; }
```

Is there a faster way of doing this? Preferably no loops.

Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't this just two `if` conditions? Why isn't this a simple function? What is the deal with adding to `fltValue`? Why a boolean when you have three different outcomes?

Comment: @tadman The comparsions are intended to be modulo 2*pi.

Comment: Consider using [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If it's modulo, then sure, `fmod` is the way to go.

Comment: use `fmod` and if it's negative add 2*pi and call it a day.

Comment: `If the float value is outside of the range 0 to 2 PI, it should still work.` It is unclear **how** it should "work" when the float value is outside of the range 0 to 2 PI. Such angle is outside of the ranges 0 and PI, or PI and 2 PI, so presumably you want to return false?

Comment: Or if you *really* want to avoid conditionals, use `fmod`, add 2 Pi, then use `fmod` again.